How to display quick action without header properly
How to fit the content properly while using Quick Action Without Header.

In the Above image, the modal is not really fitting into the default white modal which launches while using Action buttons.
This is the component code which I am using.
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="DeleteOpp" access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
        <h2 class="slds-text-heading_medium">Custom Quick Action Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium">
       This will delete the Work Item and the related records. Do you want to Proceed?
    </div>
    <div class="slds-modal__footer">
       <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.handleCancel}" />
        <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Execute" onclick="{!c.handleExecute}" class="slds-m-left_small" />
    </div>
 
</aura:component>


The same code can be tried using the Lightning:card tag. I have slightly modified your code, you can add further spacing and change formatting as per your actual needs
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
   <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
   <lightning:card class="slds-p-around_x-large">
      <aura:set attribute="title">
         <div class="slds-clearfix">
            <div class = "slds-align_absolute-center"> Quick Action Header</div>
         </div>
      </aura:set>
      <aura:set attribute="body">
         This will delete the Work Item and the related records. Do you want to Proceed?
         <div class="slds-clearfix">
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" class="slds-m-left_small slds-float_right"  />
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Execute"  class="slds-m-left_small slds-float_right" />
         </div>
      </aura:set>
   </lightning:card>
</aura:component>

The output looks like

Follow this article to know more about lightning:card: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/aura:expression/documentation
